# Do Random Effects Regressions drop respondents with only 1 wave of data?

Tags: panel-data, econometrics, stata, random-effects-model

In a random effects regression across 2 waves of panel data in Stata (or really any statistical program) like below:

xtreg health_y age_y income_y, cluster(current_county_y1) re robust

When respondents are in 1 but not both waves are these respondents included in the random effects regression? Or are they dropped?

Do only individuals with 2 waves of data get included in a random effects regression or is any wave for which they have data included?

Also is there any way to include individuals who only have one wave and would this even make sense?

Very best,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xtreg` reports the minimum number of observations per group in the output. You shouldn't see any ones there if Stata was dropping them.

You can verify this with a simple simulation where you delete the first of two observations for unit 1 and the check the e(sample), which marks estimation sample:

```
. use if id != 407 & !missing(fte) using http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/c/CardKrueger1994.dta, clear
(Dataset from Card&Krueger (1994))

. bys id: drop if _N!=2
(19 observations deleted)

. drop if id == 1 & t==0
(1 observation deleted)

. xtset id t
       panel variable:  id (unbalanced)
        time variable:  t, 0 to 1
                delta:  1 unit

. xtdes

      id:  1, 2, ..., 522                                    n =        389
       t:  0, 1, ..., 1                                      T =          2
           Delta(t) = 1 unit
           Span(t)  = 2 periods
           (id*t uniquely identifies each observation)

Distribution of T_i:   min      5%     25%       50%       75%     95%     max
                         1       2       2         2         2       2       2

     Freq.  Percent    Cum. |  Pattern
 ---------------------------+---------
      388     99.74   99.74 |  11
        1      0.26  100.00 |  .1
 ---------------------------+---------
      389    100.00         |  XX

. xtreg fte i.(treated bk kfc roys wendys t), re cluster(id)
note: 1.wendys omitted because of collinearity

Random-effects GLS regression                   Number of obs     =        777
Group variable: id                              Number of groups  =        389

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.0003                                         min =          1
     between = 0.2412                                         avg =        2.0
     overall = 0.1842                                         max =          2

                                                Wald chi2(5)      =     256.45
corr(u_i, X)   = 0 (assumed)                    Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

                                   (Std. Err. adjusted for 389 clusters in id)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
         fte |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     treated |
         NJ  |  -.9138251   .9044213    -1.01   0.312    -2.686458    .8588081
        1.bk |   .8437428   1.116946     0.76   0.450    -1.345431    3.032916
       1.kfc |  -9.291282   1.074727    -8.65   0.000    -11.39771   -7.184855
      1.roys |  -1.050834   1.306531    -0.80   0.421    -3.611588    1.509919
    1.wendys |          0  (omitted)
         1.t |  -.1174794   .4526165    -0.26   0.795    -1.004592    .7696327
       _cons |   20.18882   1.178418    17.13   0.000     17.87916    22.49848
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  5.3011202
     sigma_e |  6.2737008
         rho |  .41656354   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. count if e(sample)==0
  0
```

As you can see the singleton observation was included in the model.

Comment: Dimitriy,

Thank you for your response, could I ask you to explain further how respondents in panel data are contributing to the analysis when they only appear in the first of two waves for example? In simple terms, how is their presence in this first wave adding information to the relationship examined?

For example, in a random effects regression across 2 waves like below:
xtreg health_y age_y income_y, re
When respondents are in 1 but not both waves, how does their presence in 1 wave contribute to an overall analysis of employment change and health across 2 waves?

Comment: In the GLS transformation, you alter the data by subtracting the weighted mean for each panel: $y_{it}-\lambda \bar y_i.$ In the case of the singleton panel, $y_{it}=\bar y_i$, but because you are multiplying by $\lambda$, which is a function error variances and the number of time periods, you don't get a zero. There's also a corresponding transformation for the covariates that has the same intuition. Then you perform pooled OLS on this transformed data. So the singleton observation remains and contributes to the estimation of the slope and intercept.